# Regex Ignore first and last terminator

Tags: c#, regex

I have string in text that have uses `|` as a delimiter.

Example:

```
|2P|1|U|F8|
```

I want the result to be `2P|1|U|F8`. How can I do that?

Comment: you don't need regex to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex is very easy, but why not just use `Trim()`:

```
var str = "|2P|1|U|F8|";
str = str.Trim(new[] {'|'});
```

or just without `new[] {...}`:

```
str = str.Trim('|');
```

Output:

[image]

In case there are leading/trailing whitespaces, you can use chained Trims:

```
var str = "\r\n |2P|1|U|F8|   \r\n";
str = str.Trim().Trim('|');
```

Output will be the same.

Comment: You can simply write `.Trim('|')`. This will not work if the first or last values might be empty: `||1|U|F8|`, but that may not be an issue.

Comment: @Kobi: Old habits :) And I updated the code to return expected result even with leading/trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.Substring`:

```
string str = "|2P|1|U|F8|"; 
string newStr = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^\||\|$
```

You can try this.Replace by `empty string`.Use verbatim mode.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oF9hR9/14

Comment: It is not a verbatinum mode. It is a [verbatim string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the starting and the ending delimiter.

```
@"^\||\|$"
```

Use the below regex and then replace the match with an empty string.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^\||\|$");
string result = rgx.Replace(input, "");
```

Use mulitline modifier `m` when you're dealing with multiple lines.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?m)^\||\|$");
```

Since `|` is a special char in regex, you need to escape this in-order to match a literal `|` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "|2P|1|U|F8|";

foreach (string item in input.Split("|".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Result is:

```
2P
1
U
F8
```

Answer (score 1):

For completionists-sake, you can also use `Mid`

```
Strings.Mid("|2P|1|U|F8|", 2, s.Length - 2)
```

This will cut out the part from the second character to the previous to last one and produce the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that at some point you will want to parse the string to extract its '`|`' separated components, so here goes another alternative that goes in that direction:

```
string.Join("|", theString.Split(new[] {'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```